# WPF Application : How to add items to the "Application Menu"?

Tags: wpf

I am sorry I don't know the right name of it I just keep calling it "Application Menu". It's the menu you get when you click the applications icon in the top left corner or when you right-click on the application in the task bar.

Anyway, in my WPF application I want to add items to that menu. In my old MFC C++ days this was an easy task but for a WPF application I have no idea how to do it. Do I have to make some unmanaged API calls?

Comment: It's called 'System Menu'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have to make use of the Win32 API.  Here's a good article that should get you all the info you need:
[Add System Menu Items to WPF Window using Win32 API](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/03/Add-System-Menu-Items-to-WPF-Window-using-Win32-API.aspx)